# How can I Enable Webp support in php GD library in xampp on linux

Tags: php, linux, xampp, gd, php-7

I have **XAMPP for Linux 7.0.8**.

And enabled with **GD Support**.

[screenshot of phpinfo(); about GD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXfCP.png)

I want to use `imagewebp();`.
I have error while using this,

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagewebp()

while searching for a solution I have concluded with is solution from http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

> Image Format  | Configure Switch
>
> webp  | To enable support for webp add --with-vpx-dir=DIR . Available as of PHP 5.5.

I want to enable webp support.

What I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a Solution of Uninstalling **XAMPP** Application and installing Native **LAMP stack** server.

Why Because I cannot Recompile **PHP** in **XAMPP**. It will be more difficult.

I used My native **Linux Apache/PHP** installation instead, So I can download source packages and recompile **PHP** to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Google and build webP libraries from source code in your server.
https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download

And as far as I concerned Ubuntu and Debian does not bundle the GD libs with them because of some kind of security reasons. (I don't know which distro that you use)
You can recompile the PHP or add with this for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

don't forget the restart your web server. You can do it same for RPM packages as well.

Comment: I have already installed GD library that's why enabled with **GD Support**.... What is my question is enable **webp support**

Comment: You already enabled GD support in PHP. So did you install GD libraries into your system?

Comment: Installed GD libraries in my **XAMPP** application see my 'phpinfo();' screenshot in my _question_ area... and I installed Both **libgd** and **libwebp** libraries in My system also....