# How to enable webp within xampp

Tags: php, xampp, webp

How can I enable the “imagewebp” function in XAMPP?

The function `function_exists(‘imagewebp’)` returns false.
The XAMPP doesn’t allow that I recompile the PHP, but I must use XAMPP, my PHP version is 7.1.33.

When I run the `gd_info()` function all extensions return 1 but `webP_support`.

Comment: if you a `linux` user this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344764/how-can-i-enable-webp-support-in-php-gd-library-in-xampp-on-linux) will help you

Comment: You can go to Google and build webP libraries from source code in your server. https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download

And as far as I concerned Ubuntu and Debian does not bundle the GD libs with them because of some kind of security reasons. (I don't know which distro that you use) You can recompile the PHP or add with this for Ubuntu:

sudo apt-get install php5-gd
don't forget the restart your web server. You can do it same for RPM packages as well.